# PHP Array of images wrap five images in a div

Tags: php, loops, foreach

My mysql database outputs an array of imagenames I am stuck on this loop please he

```
  <?php foreach ($newarrivaldata as $row){ ?>
       <?php echo $row['imgfile'].'<br/>';?>
  <?php }?>
```

$newarrivaldata  has 18 image files how to 
display them like this ?

```
<div id='page1'>    img1    img2    img3    img4    img5    </div>

<div id='page2'>    img6    img7    img8    img9    img10    </div>

<div id='page3'>    img11    img12    img13    img14    img15    </div>

<div id='page4'>    img16    img17    img18                    </div>
```

**UPDATE : var_dump($newarrivaldata )**

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'idvehicle' => string '970' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Toyota RX400' (length=12)
      'imgfile' => string '12122809355412.jpg' (length=18)
      'imgtype' => string 'coverimg' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array
      'idvehicle' => string '972' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'asd' (length=3)
      'imgfile' => string '12122815555612.jpg' (length=18)
      'imgtype' => string 'coverimg' (length=8)

  ....upto 17=>
```

Comment: why you want to delete your question??

Comment: It's too late to delete a question when it already has answers.

Comment: Probably due to it's poor reception by the SO community, likely caused by the lack of effort put into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you update your question to include the output of

```
print_r($newarrivaldata);
```

If you are just looking to output the table verbatim (let me propose you reset everything to start with i=0, rows and columns, we don't start with 1's, we always start with 0's, so page0, img0, etc):

```
$numColumns = 5;
for($row=0; $row<ceil(count($newarrivaldata)/$numColumns); $row++){
   echo "\n<div id='page$row'>";
   for($c=0; $c<$numColumns; $c++){
      if(isset($newarrivaldata[$row+$col])){
         echo '<img src="'.$newarrivaldata[$row+$col]['imgfile'].'" />';
      }
   }
   echo "</div>"
}
```

What I've done is taken your array, and split it into rows of 5, but changing $numColumns to another value will split it into rows of $numColumns columns. The reason I had to take count($newarrivaldata)/$numColumns) is that if your array is not an exact multiple of $numColumns, you will get warnings from PHP, so I am just trying to avoid that.

Comment: Tx for the answer I have updated the question !

Comment: In that case, try my for loop, your var_dump looks pretty much how I expected, so the for loop I wrote is perfect. Well, since I typed it in my browser it may have 1 or 2 syntax errors like a missing bracket, but is the right row/col output to spit out the HTML you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, this will be a starting point

```
<?php
$newarrivaldata = array("one", "two", "three", "four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","elevn","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighten"); 
 $key=1;
foreach ($newarrivaldata as $row){ 
      echo $row."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
     if($key%5 == 0) echo "<br/>";
    $key++;
  }?>
```

[Working demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/317-t3g)